# Returning value of a HashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

so I have been able to put objects into my hash map successfully, but  I'm having trouble returning an object. When I used an arrayList for this same project, I simply displayed it with the following method:

```
public void displayDetails(int currentItem) {   
    accountIDTextField.setText(table.get(currentItem).getAccountID()+"");
    accountNumberTextField.setText(table.get(currentItem).getAccountNumber());
    surnameTextField.setText(table.get(currentItem).getSurname());
    accountTypeTextField.setText(table.get(currentItem).getAccountType());
}
```

And pressing the 'first' button would go to the number 1 in the list.

```
first.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentItem = 1;
            displayDetails(currentItem);            
        }
    });
```

As for my hashing, I have used the accountNumber as the key, (hashed by using the % modulo function)

Working backwards, I can get the accountID when I pass in the accountNumber as a parameter in the get() method.

```
hashMap.get(12345678).getAccountID();
```

But how do I return the accountID if I just want to get the first object stored in the hash map(i.e get accountID without knowing accountNumber)?

(AccountID is an integer unique to a particular account and will be automatically generated when a new account record is created)

Sorry if this isn't worded very well, I'm still trying to get my head around Java and OOP in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'd be curious to know if you need both an account number and account ID?

Answer (score 1):

hope I understood you right. getting only the first item of a HashMap would be something like:

```
Map<String, String> myhashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myhashmap.entrySet().iterator().next();
```

Comment: Just to point out that this will generate a warning that the type is raw, but this never has been an issue for minor tasks such as this.

Comment: Thanks, that returns the second item in the HashMap though? And I need to eventually add 'next' 'previous' and 'last' buttons. This can't be done the same way no?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the Map by using Map.values().
I would't access the value based on it's order in the map because ordering is not guaranteed. You should give each one a defined number. Then you can access them like:

```
Object o = map.values().get(id);
```

to get the first:

```
Object o = map.values().get(0);
```

Comment: You might not know the id of the first element. @TwelveDollar's answer shows how you can get it without knowing any key (first element).